# Python - Interactive phonebook

Tags: python, split, interactive

I need help with adding a name and phone number to a dictionary in ONE line with `raw_input`. It should look like this: `add John 123` (adds the name John with the number 123). Here is my code:

```
def phonebook():
    pb={}
    while True:
        val,q,w=raw_input().split(" ")
        if val=='add':
            if q in pb:
                print
                print "This name already exists"
                print
            else:
                pb[q]=w #lägger till namn + nummer i dictionary
        if val=='lookup':
            if q in pb:
                print
                print pb[q]
                print
            else:
                print "Name is not in phonebook"
                print
```

Im getting the unpack error. Any tips? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The following line assume that you type exactly 3 words each separated by a space character:

```
val, q, w = raw_input().split(" ")
```

If you have less or more than 3 words (which is the case when you use the lookup command, isn't it?), you will get an unpack error.

You could get the input in a unique variable and then test its first element to avoid error:

```
in_ = raw_input().split(" ")
if in_[0] == 'add':
    # process add action
if in_[0] == 'lookup':
    # process lookup action
```

---

bonus tip: you do not need to give the space character to `split` method since it is the default value:

```
raw_input().split()  # will work as well
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think you get an unpack error when you lookup someone with "lookup john". The code looks for a third value in the split(" ") but doesn't find one.

I'm not sure if this might help:

```
def phonebook():
pb={}
while True:
    vals = raw_input().split(" ")
    if vals[0] == 'add':
        q = vals[1]
        w = vals[2]
        if q in pb:
            print "This name already exists"
        else:
            pb[q]=w #lägger till namn + nummer i dictionary
    elif vals[0]=='lookup':
        q = vals[1]
        if q in pb:
            print
            print str(q) + "'s number is: " + str(pb[q])
            print
        else:
            print "Name is not in phonebook"
            print
```

return me with:

```
>add j 12
>add j 12
This name already exists
>lookup j

j's number is: 12

>lookup j 12

j's number is: 12

>lookup k
Name is not in phonebook
```